# Creating a vector of all instances of a class when objects are being instantiated in a loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to keep a pointer to all of the instances of a class inside of a static member variable.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Person {
public:
  static std::vector<Person*> allPeople;
  int age;
  Person(int a) {
    age = a;
    allPeople.push_back(this);
  }
};

std::vector<Person*> Person::allPeople;


int main() {
  static std::vector<Person> children;

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    children.push_back(Person(i));
  }

  for(int i=0;i<Person::allPeople.size();i++) {
    std::cout << Person::allPeople[i]->age;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Right now, this code has 10 instances of the same object stored inside `Person::allPeople`. I think that it has to do something with how every time it loops around, the object goes out of scope. One of my solutions would be to make copies of the object and add pointers to those, except  in my actual code, the objects' values would be changing frequently. If anyone knows what the best solution is please let me know, sorry if this is a bit of a messy question I can clarify if needed.

Comment: Why do you need a `Person*` pointer stored in that vector in 1st place?That doesn't make sense for me. A `std::shared_ptr<Person>` would probably a better choice.

Comment: Keeping pointers to objects stored in a `vector` is a problem if the `vector` resizes and all the items are copied to new locations.

Comment: `Person(i)` creates a temporary object that gets logged in the vector. Inside `push_back` that object gets copied into `children`; the copied object does not get logged. Then the temporary object gets destroyed, but its address doesn’t get removed from `allPeople`. Repeat ten times, each temporary is at the same address.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Can you add context to your question? Why do you **need** to store each instance in a static member variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 children.push_back(Person(i));
```

This is what happens here:

1. `Person(i)` creates a temporary object. `Person`'s constructor saves a pointer to this object in its private `allPeople` vector.
2. The temporary object gets `push_back`ed into the `children` vector. This copies/moves this object into the vector. The vector holds a copy of the original object that was added to it. The vector now has a completely different instance of the `Person` object, that was copy/move-constructed.
3. After `push_back()` returns, the temporary `Person` object gets destroyed. `allPeople` is left with a dangling pointer to a destroyed object.

The reason you're seeing ten copies of the same pointer is because, it just so happens, every instance of the temporary object gets created in automatic scope at the same memory address. The shown code is completely blind to copy-constructed instances of `Person`, they get completely missed.

The rules of automatically and dynamically-scoped objects in C++ are complicated, and everything must be handled correctly. At the very least:

1. `Person()` must implement a destructor to remove its `this` pointer from the `allPeople` vector.
2. `Person` must implement, at the very least, a copy constructor that also stores the `this` pointer of the copy-constructed object in `allPeople`.

P.S. And let's not forget that every time `std::vector` reallocates its contents, this creates another batch of copy/move constructed objects, with the old objects getting destroyed.